# Loop specific values from deep nested hash and array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby and am having difficulty with looping through deep nested hashes and arrays.

Say I have the following JSON:

```
{  
   "Resume":{  
               .... data ....
      },
      "StructuredXMLResume":{  
         "ContactInfo":{  
               .... data ....
               }
            ]
         },
         "EmploymentHistory":{  
            "EmployerOrg":[  
               {  
                  "EmployerOrgName":"ABC Corp.",
                  "PositionHistory":[  
                     {  
               .... data ....
                  ]
               },
               {  
                  "EmployerOrgName":"National Geo.",
                  "PositionHistory":[  
                     {  
            .... data ....
                           }
                        ]

                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
```

.

```
resume.["Resume"]["StructuredXMLResume"]["EmploymentHistory"]["EmployerOrg"][0]["EmployerOrgName"]
```

gives me `ABC Corp.` and

```
resume.["Resume"]["StructuredXMLResume"]["EmploymentHistory"]["EmployerOrg"][1]["EmployerOrgName"]
```

gives me `National Geo.`

How do I loop to print each `EmployerOrgName`?

Comment: Also should I use `each` or `map`? I am confused with the difference between both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
resume.["Resume"]["StructuredXMLResume"]["EmploymentHistory"]["EmployerOrg"].each do |employer_org|
  puts employer_org["EmployerOrgName"] # or whatever you want to do with the employer_org hash
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a enumerator, like each, on any "thing" that either is or behaves like an array/hash object, so in this case you would want to:

```
all_employerorgs = resume.["Resume"]["StructuredXMLResume"]["EmploymentHistory"]["EmployerOrg"]
# which is an array of hashes that then you can iterate through 
# you could iterate directly on that but for readibility 
# I would always assign it to a var
all_employerorgs.each do |employerorg|
  puts employerorg['EmployerOrgName']
end
```